# c++ multiple levels of templating

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to define two templated types:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A {};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using BType = std::vector<typename A<T1, T2>>::iterator;
```

I'm receiving an error of invalid templates. I wonder what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the position of [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename),

> Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, `typename` can be used to declare that a [dependent qualified name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) is a type.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
using BType = typename std::vector<A<T1, T2>>::iterator;
//            ^^^^^^^^
```